# Getting multiple matches per string for a vector of strings

Tags: r, regex, string, parsing, character

I have some text that looks as follows:

```
P17-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR] - Movimiento Bolivia Libre [MBL] [MNR-MBL])
P18-Socialist Party (Partido Socialista [PS])
P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])

All_Election_Parties <- readr::read_lines("All_Election_Parties.txt")
```

The code: `str_match_all(entry, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])")` creates a list of matches.

```
[1] [MBL] 
[2] [MNR-MBL]
[3] [PS]
[4] [LJ]
```

What I want however is for it to create a list/column/vector with a vector/list of all matches for each string. Something like this:

```
[1] [MBL] [MNR-MBL]
[2] [PS]
[3] [LJ]
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own solution `str_match_all(entry, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])")` creates a list of matrices. Simply `drop`ing in each list should yield your desired result:

```r
entry <- c("P17-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR] - Movimiento Bolivia Libre [MBL] [MNR-MBL])",
           "P18-Socialist Party (Partido Socialista [PS])",
           "P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])")


library(stringr)
library(purrr)

str_match_all(entry, "(?<=\\[).+?(?=\\])") %>% map(drop)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "MNR"     "MBL"     "MNR-MBL"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "PS"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "LJ"
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract_all`

```
stringr::str_extract_all(All_Election_Parties, "\\[.+?\\]")
#[[1]]
#[1] "[MNR]"     "[MBL]"     "[MNR-MBL]"

#[[2]]
#[1] "[PS]"

#[[3]]
#[1] "[LJ]"
```

and similarly in base R

```
regmatches(All_Election_Parties, gregexpr("\\[.+?\\]", All_Election_Parties))
```

**data**

```
text <- "P17-Nationalist Revolutionary Movement-Free Bolivia Movement (Movimiento Nacionalista Revolucionario [MNR] - Movimiento Bolivia Libre [MBL] [MNR-MBL])
P18-Socialist Party (Partido Socialista [PS])
P19-Liberty and Justice (Libertad y Justicia [LJ])"


All_Election_Parties <- readr::read_lines(text)
```